# LiveData triggers only once when paging with room

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging

ViewModel:

```
val eventDataFactory = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)!!.eventDao().getEventList()

    val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
            .setPrefetchDistance(2)
            .setPageSize(10).build()

    eventListResponse = LivePagedListBuilder(eventDataFactory, pagedListConfig)
            .build()


    fun getEventListLiveData(): LiveData<PagedList<Event>> {
    return eventListResponse!!
}
```

Fragment:

```
viewModel.getEventListLiveData().observe(this@Fragment, Observer {
        Log.d("Fragment", "eventList Update: " + it!!.size)
        for (event: Event in it) {
            if (event != null)
                Log.d("Fragment", "EventId: " + event.eventId)
        }
        eventListAdapter!!.submitList(it)

    })
```

EventDao:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM event")
fun getEventList(): DataSource.Factory<Int,Event>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAll(events: List<Event>): List<Long>
```

I have 55 entries in my local database and I suppose to get 10 entries on each scroll. I only get `eventList Update: 10` for first time, after that adapter gets updated value but observer did not triggers. 
Also when I insert new value in database I observer returned only first 10 value instead of newly added value.

Comment: completely cannot understand what are you trying to do with this code, you even don't have `LiveData` object to update him with new data

Comment: Just updated Dao code, I have insertAll function. I want updated value when user insert new data or scroll the recyclerview

Comment: @pskink my code is similar to official documentation. doesn't work

Comment: yes I tried that code but no luck. I need that for loop to run with updated eventIds on new data and on scroll.

Comment: Yes that loop only. I need observer to get data on every scroll. I am getting it only on very first time.

Comment: Okay let me try again.